# Converting images to video

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, h.264, android-mediacodec

how can I convert images to video **without** using [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/), only with android [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html). The images for video is bitmap files that can be ARGB888 or YUV420 (my choice). The most important thing is that the video have to be playable in android devices and the maximum API is 16. I know all about API 18 [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) and I **can not** use it.

Please help me, I am stuck on this for many days. 
(JCodec to slow, and FFmpeg very complicated to use).

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Since there's an answer I'll add it as a comment: Basically, for this case (API 16), I'd use MediaCodec, the result can be simply saved to a file as a .h264 file. Then the result can be mux in an MP4 using Mp4Parser/IsoParser library, available as a java open source lib.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this in API 16 that works across all devices.

You will encounter problems with [buffer alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699009/how-to-get-stride-and-y-plane-alignment-values-for-mediacodec-encoder/20707645#20707645), [color spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match), and the need to use different YUV [layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806987/how-to-use-bytebuffer-in-the-mediacodec-context-in-android/15770611#15770611) on different [devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096726/how-to-encode-bitmaps-into-a-video-using-mediacodec/17114872#17114872).

Consider the buffer alignment issue.  On pre-API 18 devices with Qualcomm SOCs, you had to align the CbCr planes at a 2K offset from the start of the buffer.  On API 18, all devices use the same layout; this is enforced by CTS tests that were added in Android 4.3.

Even with API 18 you still have to runtime detect whether the encoder wants planar or semi-planar values.  (It's probably not relevant for your situation, but none of the YUV formats output by the camera are accepted by `MediaCodec`.)  Note there is no RGB input to `MediaCodec`.

If portability is not a concern, i.e. you're targeting a specific device, your code will be much simpler.

There are code snippets in the SO pages linked above.  The closest "official" example is the buffer-to-buffer / buffer-to-surface tests in [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest).  These are API 18 tests, which means they don't do the "if QC and API16 then change buffer alignment" dance, but they do show how to do the planar vs. semi-planar layout detection.  It doesn't include an RGB-to-YUV color converter, but there are examples of such around the web.

On the bright side, the encoder *output* seems to be just fine on any device and API version.

Converting the raw H.264 stream to a .mp4 file requires a 3rd-party library, since as you noted `MediaMuxer` is not available.  I believe some people have installed [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) as a command-line utility and executed it that way (maybe like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768439/convert-h-264-avi-container-to-mp4-with-ffmpeg)?).

Answer (score 6):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaCodecList;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class MMediaMuxer {
    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc"; // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static int _width = 512;
    private static int _height = 512;
    private static final int BIT_RATE = 800000;
    private static final int INFLAME_INTERVAL = 1;
    private static final int FRAME_RATE = 10;
    private static boolean DEBUG = false;
    private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
    private MediaMuxer mediaMuxer;
    private boolean mRunning;
    private int generateIndex = 0;
    private int mTrackIndex;
    private int MAX_FRAME_VIDEO = 0;
    private List<byte[]> bitList;
    private List<byte[]> bitFirst;
    private List<byte[]> bitLast;
    private int current_index_frame = 0;

    private static final String TAG = "CODEC";
    private String outputPath;
    private Activity _activity;

    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private String _title;
    private String _mess;

    public void Init(Activity activity, int width, int height, String title, String mess) {
        _title = title;
        _mess = mess;
        _activity = activity;
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        Logd("MMediaMuxer Init");
        ShowProgressBar();

    }

    private Handler aHandler = new Handler();



    public void AddFrame(final byte[] byteFrame) {
        CheckDataListState();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Logd("Android get Frame");
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteFrame, 0, byteFrame.length);
                Logd("Android convert Bitmap");
                byte[] byteConvertFrame = getNV21(bit.getWidth(), bit.getHeight(), bit);
                Logd("Android convert getNV21");
                bitList.add(byteConvertFrame);
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public void AddFrame(byte[] byteFrame, int count, boolean isLast) {
        CheckDataListState();
        Logd("Android get Frames = " + count);
        Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteFrame, 0, byteFrame.length);
        Logd("Android convert Bitmap");
        byteFrame = getNV21(bit.getWidth(), bit.getHeight(), bit);
        Logd("Android convert getNV21");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (isLast) {
                bitLast.add(byteFrame);
            } else {
                bitFirst.add(byteFrame);
            }
        }
    }

    public void CreateVideo() {
        current_index_frame = 0;
        Logd("Prepare Frames Data");
        bitFirst.addAll(bitList);
        bitFirst.addAll(bitLast);
        MAX_FRAME_VIDEO = bitFirst.size();
        Logd("CreateVideo");
        mRunning = true;
        bufferEncoder();
    }

    public boolean GetStateEncoder() {
        return mRunning;
    }

    public String GetPath() {
        return outputPath;
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        mRunning = false;
    }

    public void ShowProgressBar() {
        _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(_activity);
                pd.setTitle(_title);
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.setMessage(_mess);
                pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pd.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void HideProgressBar() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void bufferEncoder() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Logd("PrepareEncoder start");
                    PrepareEncoder();
                    Logd("PrepareEncoder end");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Loge(e.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    while (mRunning) {
                        Encode();
                    }
                } finally {
                    Logd("release");
                    Release();
                    HideProgressBar();
                    bitFirst = null;
                    bitLast = null;
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void ClearTask() {
        bitList = null;
        bitFirst = null;
        bitLast = null;
    }


    private void PrepareEncoder() throws IOException {
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
        if (codecInfo == null) {
            Loge("Unable to find an appropriate codec for " + MIME_TYPE);
        }
        Logd("found codec: " + codecInfo.getName());
        int colorFormat;
        try {
            colorFormat = selectColorFormat(codecInfo, MIME_TYPE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            colorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;
        }

        mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());
        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, _width, _height);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, INFLAME_INTERVAL);
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();
        try {
            String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
                    "pixel"+currentDateTimeString+".mp4").toString();
            mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Loge("MediaMuxer creation failed");
        }
    }


    private void Encode() {
        while (true) {
            if (!mRunning) {
                break;
            }
            Logd("Encode start");
            long TIMEOUT_USEC = 5000;
            int inputBufIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
            long ptsUsec = computePresentationTime(generateIndex, FRAME_RATE);
            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                byte[] input = bitFirst.get(current_index_frame);
                final ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                inputBuffer.clear();
                inputBuffer.put(input);
                mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, input.length, ptsUsec, 0);
                generateIndex++;
            }
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int encoderStatus = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // no output available yet
                Loge("No output from encoder available");
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                MediaFormat newFormat = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
                mTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                mediaMuxer.start();
            } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                Loge("unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
            } else if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                ByteBuffer encodedData = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
                if (encodedData == null) {
                    Loge("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                } else {
                    encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);
                    mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);
                    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                }
            }
            current_index_frame++;
            if (current_index_frame > MAX_FRAME_VIDEO - 1) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mRunning = false;");
                mRunning = false;
            }
            Logd("Encode end");
        }
    }


    private void Release() {
        if (mediaCodec != null) {
            mediaCodec.stop();
            mediaCodec.release();
            mediaCodec = null;
            Logd("RELEASE CODEC");
        }
        if (mediaMuxer != null) {
            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            mediaMuxer = null;
            Logd("RELEASE MUXER");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns the first codec capable of encoding the specified MIME type, or
     * null if no match was found.
     */
    private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType) {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
            if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
            for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                    return codecInfo;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a color format that is supported by the codec and by this test
     * code. If no match is found, this throws a test failure -- the set of
     * formats known to the test should be expanded for new platforms.
     */
    private static int selectColorFormat(MediaCodecInfo codecInfo,
                                         String mimeType) {
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo
                .getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
        for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length; i++) {
            int colorFormat = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
            if (isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat)) {
                return colorFormat;
            }
        }
        return 0; // not reached
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this is a color format that this test code understands
     * (i.e. we know how to read and generate frames in this format).
     */
    private static boolean isRecognizedFormat(int colorFormat) {
        switch (colorFormat) {
            // these are the formats we know how to handle for
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {

        int[] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

        scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        byte[] yuv = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 / 2];
        encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        scaled.recycle();

        return yuv;
    }

    private void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int yIndex = 0;
        int uvIndex = frameSize;

        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;


                Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;


                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));

                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckDataListState() {
        if (bitList == null) {
            bitList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (bitFirst == null) {
            bitFirst = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (bitLast == null) {
            bitLast = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private long computePresentationTime(long frameIndex, int framerate) {
        return 132 + frameIndex * 1000000 / framerate;
    }

    private static void Logd(String Mess) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, Mess);
        }
    }

    private static void Loge(String Mess) {
        Log.e(TAG, Mess);
    }
}
```

Works with 21 SDK. Do not pay attention to several lists. So it was done since the conversion of a piece of data goes in runtime.

Comment: can you make it record audio as well?

Comment: also seems it doesn't record dynamically can you make it record dynamically? I want to use it with onPreviewFrame and its byte arrays

Comment: This example creates a video from the existing content, from the pictures. Therefore, by the time you create a video, all the content should already be there.

Comment: @VadimTeselkin yes I understood it already, but still can this example be changed to record real-time?

Comment: @VadimTeselkin when I'm tryind to add byte array (frame) to your function (`addFrame`) I get exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @VadimTeselkin also I don't understand why do you need bitmaps (convert something), we can use `parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);`

Comment: You get an error because Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray (byteFrame, 0, byteFrame.length);
bit == null
Check that you do pass bitmap...

Comment: @VadimTeselkin .. Do you have working examples for above code.. I am getting error like :   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to stop the muxer..

Comment: Hi @VadimTeselkin I trying to convert list of images to video using your above code. which is not happening.. help me to fix this.. Thanks

Comment: I seem to be getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't stop due to wrong state.` error when trying to stop the muxer, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: in my case : `android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffc0e`