# How to properly save frames from mp4 as png files using ExtractMpegFrames.java?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, yuv

I am trying to get all frames from an mp4 file using the ExtractMpegFrames.java class found here http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest.java.txt

What I currently do is create a temp file (File.createTempFile) in a directory that stores all the frames, create a FileOutputStream and do

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut)
```

where fOut is the OutputStream with the file.

Currently, the saved images look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfy4R.jpg

Using the Camera2 Api, I record a video and save it as an mp4. According to VLC, the color space for the video is Planar 4:2:0 YUV Full Scale.

Looking around, it seems that each vendor uses different color spaces
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21266510/7351748. I know ffmpeg can conversions with color spaces, but I cannot use it.

I am not sure where to start to solve this issue of the strange output pngs. I am assuming that this is a color space issue, but I can be completely wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all Frames of Video Using ffmpeg library here is working code.

add dependancy

```
compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

to your gradle

```
      private void loadFFMpegBinary() {
        try {
            if (ffmpeg == null) {
                ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
            }
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
//                @Override
//                public void onFailure() {
//                    showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
//                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ffmpeg : correct Loaded");
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "EXception  : " + e);
        }
    }
```

here is image extratct method

```
 public void extractImagesVideo() {
        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
        );

        String filePrefix = "extract_picture";
        String fileExtn = ".jpg";
        String yourRealPath = getPath(Pick_Video.this, DataModel.selectedVideoUri);
        Log.d("selected url", "" + DataModel.selectedVideoUri);
        File src = new File(yourRealPath).getAbsoluteFile();

        File appDir=new File(moviesDir,"/"+app_name+"/");
        if(!appDir.exists())
            appDir.mkdir();
        DataModel.appDir=appDir;
        File dir = new File(appDir, "testVideo");
        int fileNo = 0;
        while (dir.exists()) {
            fileNo++;
            dir = new File(moviesDir+"/"+app_name+"/", "testVideo" + fileNo);

        }
        dir.mkdir();
        DataModel.dir = dir;

        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(256);

        filePath = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        File dest = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);


        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + src.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());


        String[] complexCommand = { "-i",""+src.toString(),"-qscale:v", "2","-vf", "fps=fps=20/1",dest.getAbsolutePath()};
        //"-qscale:v", "2","-vf", "fps=fps=20/1",//
        //works fine with speed and
        execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);



    }
```

call this two method on button click event

Comment If Any query.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using FFmpeg?

Comment: i have no idea about how to do this without ffmpeg but according to me best way to use ffmpeg you can set numbers of frames, and qulity of images this type of things you can do with ffmpeg